# Shrink a div without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In my angular application, i am having the header as like the format,

```
-- Header --

-- Sub header --

-- Search Box --

-- Create and Search Button --

-- Scroll Div --
```

**Html:**

```
<h1> Header </h1>
<h3> Sub header </h3>
<div class="search-box-wrapper">
    <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="search"> <br><br><br>
    <button type="button"> Create </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button type="button"> Search </button> <br><br>
</div>

<div class="scroll-div">
  <ul>
    <li> <h1> User One </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Two </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Three </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Four </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Five </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Six </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Seven </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Eight </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Nine </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Ten </h1> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

**Css:**

```
.search-box {
   border-radius: 25px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
}

.scroll-div {
   height: calc(100vh - 400px);
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

And **working stackblitz** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhnt8q

Here i have a div which has class name `scroll-div` with list items which is **scrollable**..

If i start the scroll, then i need to shrink the `search-wrapper` (create and search button to be hidden)..

Again on scroll reaches the up point then it should be normal..

The expected output is like google search..

**Initial** search results will be like,

[image]

Whereas on **scroll start**s it will get shrinks like,

[image]

In the same way i need to hide create and search button on scroll starts and show only search box (shrinked) and on scroll top again need to show the create and search button..

Kindly help me to achieve the expected result **without jquery** ..

Any **angular** way results would help me more..

Comment: you mean sticky navbar?

Comment: check this bro https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7bng7

Comment: Bro did you worked out in any of the slider using pure angular and typescript without jquery or third party library? If you have or find any please share the link bro..

Comment: https://netbasal.com/understanding-angular-structural-directives-659acd0f67e

Comment: @Chellappan, Thanks bro..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To hide and show*** element you could get by the ***element id***

Use event method on .html and on .ts file add the following function:

html: `(scroll)="scroll($event.target.value)` which are used to ***detect scroll***

ts:

```
scroll(val) {
    let scroll = document.getElementById('scroll');

    if (scroll.scrollTop == 0) {
      this.isShow = 'show';
    } else {
      this.isShow = 'hide';
    }
  }
```

***Check the following [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tbmje)***

---

To add the animation you need to import:

```
import {
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    animate,
    transition
} from '@angular/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
```

Then add

```
 animations: [
     trigger('toggleHeight', [
            state('hide', style({
                height: '0px',
                opacity: '0',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                // display: 'none'
            })),
            state('show', style({
                height: '*',
                opacity: '1',
                // display: 'block'
            })),
            transition('hide => show', animate('200ms ease-in')),
            transition('show => hide', animate('200ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ],
```

Don't forget to include the following:
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` and
 ***`BrowserAnimationsModule`*** on module @NgModule import

***For further information on angular information you can check [here](https://angular.io/guide/animations) / [demo](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/animations/stackblitz)***

Comment: Your solution comes closer to what i need.. It would be better if you add shrink effect (animation transition like) rather than sudden show/hide a div..

Comment: How can i remove the break after input search box only on scroll starts ??.. Because i am getting little white space in that place on scroll starts.. If possible please update the stackblitz with removing that three ```<br><br><br>``` tags on scroll starts..

Comment: just place the <br> syntaxes inside div. check the update. or might as well remove the <br> syntaxes and modify <div id="sos" [@toggleHeight]="isShow"> with style="margin-top: value;" where value is the margin you want

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean parameter and on scroll set `flase` and use `*ngIf` to show/hide buttons and check if `event.target.scrollTop > 0`.

[See blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kttro3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<h1> Header </h1>
<h3> Sub header </h3>
<div class="search-box-wrapper">
    <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="search"> <br><br><br>
    <button type="button" *ngIf="scrollable"> Create </button> &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button type="button" *ngIf="scrollable"> Search </button> <br><br>
</div>
<p> <b> While Scroll startes in the below div and shrink the above create and search </b> </p>
<div class="scroll-div" (scroll)="onscroll($event)">
  <ul>
    <li> <h1> User One </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Two </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Three </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Four </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Five </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Six </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Seven </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Eight </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Nine </h1> </li>
    <li> <h1> User Ten </h1> </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

**TS**

```
  scrollable:boolean=true;
  onscroll(event:any){
    console.log(event.target.scrollTop)
    if (event.target.scrollTop > 0) {
      this.scrollable=false;
    }
    else{
      this.scrollable=true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: No it hides from that place in your solution i need to shrink it.. Means the below content (scroll-div) need to go to top (below search box) on scroll (As the create and search button is hidden).. Also what happens in your solution if the scroll again reached top?? I couldn't see anything..

Comment: I need to make the scroll-div to go below the search box.. Here in your solution the create and search button alone keeps hiding.. As like the another solution it should move to top below search box but i need shrink effect..

Comment: do you have any example or css code of whats you mean?

Comment: Yes i have mentioned in question expectation is like google search.. After typing any word an search.. After start scrolling it, all the menus will be hidden except search box..The effect will also be smooth on shrink.. Then on scroll to top and again with that smooth shrink effect all the menus will be displayed..

Comment: In your solution the create and search button hides from that place and shows at the same place.. But ```scroll-div``` needs to go top because there creates a white space in the place of create and search button..

Comment: If you search something in google and make scroll up and down, the same effect i am in the need..

Comment: so you  have to chang your html that the scroll be on all page...(as in google)

Comment: No i am expecting the shrink effect like that in smooth manner.. I am having this only page.. The css shrink effect i am in the need on scroll down and up and also need to have ```scroll-div``` to move above in place of hidden create and search button.. I hope you can see that space is empty in  your solution if we start scroll.. To move the ```scroll-div``` to upward below search box and on reaches up it needs to comeback to original with same css effect.. Thats is all my requirement..

Comment: the space because you use <br> remove them!!

Comment: The expected result is achieved by @Mukyuu with animation effect.. Thanks for your help and time..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve sticky navbar by only CSS3. I hope it will be useful.

**HTML: app.component.html**

```
<h1> Header </h1>
<h3> Sub header </h3>
<div class="search-container">
  <div class="search-box-wrapper">
      <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="search">
      <div class="search-box-btn">
        <button type="button"> Create </button>
        <button type="button"> Search </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-div">
    <ul>
      <li> <h1> User One </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Two </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Three </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Four </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Five </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Six </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Seven </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Eight </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Nine </h1> </li>
      <li> <h1> User Ten </h1> </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS : app.component.css**

```
.search-container{
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 400px);
}
.search-box-wrapper{
  position: sticky;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  background-color:#fff;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
.search-box-wrapper .search-box {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.search-box-wrapper input{
    width: 100%;
}
.search-box-wrapper .search-box-btn{
    margin-top:10px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.search-box-wrapper button{
  margin-right:20px;
}
```